# Getting :The website has been blocked as per order of Ministry of electronics and information technology under IT Act, 2000 stack overflow

Tags: java, angularjs, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare

We have a web application where we use

- JAVA updated with
- AngularJs
- Cloudflare as domain mapping
- We also use GCP load balancing

We have seen the message

"The website has been blocked as per order of Ministry of electronics and information technology under IT Act, 2000 stack overflow"

on particular pages only and not on the whole domain

I have confirmed that our files in the CDN are not modified recently.
There was no rerouting in the load balancer.

The issue for found in Two different users in two different network.

Please help what mighty be the issue . and suggest the next best step.

Comment: What is the URL?

Comment: Just got the article that is similar to my usecase 


The two users that were having the issue temporarily were using Airtel and Act as their ISP.


Also one thing different from normal blocking is that , only particular html files are getting replaced with the string. 
https://www.indiatoday.in/technology/features/story/blocking-websites-is-secret-in-india-now-researchers-are-probing-airtel-and-act-networks-to-reveal-details-1885025-2021-12-07

Comment: @JohnHanley The url is https://web.mightyme.in

Comment: http://www.videolan.org/contribute/

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happen to me. In firefox working fine, but in chrome getting this
"The website has been blocked as per order of Ministry of Electronics and Information Technology under IT Act, 2000."
created file name https://www.buyday.in/stylecss.css

May be because of Cloudflare. I am also using cloudflare.

Comment: This is a comment, rather than an answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @srilatha srilu ,My friend too had the similar experience on some ecommerce website recently.